# Qualitative understanding of negative step potential problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, scattering

In QM textbooks the single step potential problem is explained in  great detail. However, it is hard to understand what happens when $V_{0}<0$. Could anyone please explain qualitatively, how the incident wave, transmitted wave, and the reflected wave behave?
$V(x) = 0   (x > 0)$
$V(x) = V_{0}, V_{0}<0,  (x \le 0)$

Answer (score 1):

The zero of potential can be shifted up and down arbitrarily. What matters is the difference E-V, where E is the kinetic energy of the particle. The solution is the same.

Comment: Isn't there any difference between step-up and step-down cases?